# CanCanCan refuses to load collection for :create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

In my `PromoCodesController` I have this code:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :restaurant, find_by: :permalink
load_resource :discount, through: :restaurant
load_resource :promo_code, collection: [:create], through: :discount
```

It should be good since in `#index`, it loads the collection `@promo_codes` and in `#create` it loads `@promo_code`.

But it does not load the collection `@promo_codes` in `#create`. Where is the problem? In the documentation it says:

> :collection argument: Specify which actions are resource collection actions in addition to :index.

Thank you

Comment: _"But it does not load the collection"_ - How do you ensure that the collection is not loaded?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh pry ls, shows '@promo_code', not '@promo_codes'. And of course '@promo_codes'.class is nil

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because Cancancan's method `load_resource` ([controller_resource_loader.rb](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/585e5ea54c900c6afd536f143cde962ccdf68607/lib/cancan/controller_resource_loader.rb#L14)) assumes
only one resource variable to be set at a time: either `resource_instance` or `collection_instance`.

Your `load_resource collection: [:create]` can load `@promo_codes` in `#create` action via monkey patch to `CanCan::ControllerResourceLoader`:

```rb
# config/initializers/cancan.rb
 
module CanCan
  module ControllerResourceLoader
    def load_resource
      return if skip?(:load)

      # Original condition has been split into two separate conditions

      if load_instance?
        self.resource_instance ||= load_resource_instance
      end

      if load_collection?
        self.collection_instance ||= load_collection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The common way in which this patch works is a create form integrated into index action:

```rb
class TicketsController < ActionController::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource collection: [:create]

  def index
    @ticket = Ticket.new    
  end

  def create
    if @ticket.valid?
      @ticket.create_for_user! params[:message]
      redirect_to ticket_path(@ticket)
    else
      # @tickets are also defined here
      render :index
    end
  end
end
```